# Binding to a 2nd properties if the 1st one is "undefined"

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I won't copy/paste my whole xaml file. It will be too long to explain it but here is what is interesting : I got a Binding of a Property "Name"

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

The thing is that sometimes, my item doesn't have a "Name" property. It doesn't crash but I simply got an empty Text in my TextBlock

What I would to do, if Name is empty, is to be binded to "nothing", just {Binding}. This will display my Object name and it will be perfect !

Thanks in advance for any help, and sorry if it is a noobie question :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want here is a [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx).

In particular, it would look something like (exact syntax may need some verification):

```
         <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Name"/>
                    <Binding />
                </PriorityBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
         </TextBlock>
```

Note that this specifically falls back when the Name property is not available on the object being bound; if the Name property has an empty string value, I believe it will still use that empty value.

Comment: <TextBlock.Text> is not accepted but ur solution sounds great !

Comment: Try: <TextBlock >
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Name"/>
                    <Binding />
                </PriorityBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>

Comment: @Guillaume, Dylan edited it to show the full syntax; in general, `<Type.Property>` is the XAML syntax for setting the value of a property with a more complex construct, rather than an inline value.  The `{Binding...}` markup extension is just a shortcut for creating these `Binding` class instances.  The XAML compiler then does some additional special-case magic to realize Text is a DependencyProperty, so it allows the value to be 'set' to a Binding, which it handles by calling the various BindingOperations functions required to wire things up.

Comment: Here is my next (and final) question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244658/binding-to-the-object-gettype

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a style with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- In this binding you could inject a converter which checks for more than null -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{x:Null}">
                     <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            <Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Seems to work but I gotta know something to be sure, when I just use {Binding}. To what property the field is binded ?

Comment: @Guillaume, `{Binding}` means to use the value of the current DataContext as the value to assign to the property.  In other words an empty Path means just use the object instance itself rather than one of its properties.  Here is a handy cheat sheet for Binding syntax: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

Comment: @GuillaumeCogranne {Binding} will bind to whatever your current data context is set to. So instead of binding to the Name property of a class, you bind to the class that contains the Name property.

Comment: here is my next and final question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244658/binding-to-the-object-gettype

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to bind to the object type name you could use TargetNullValue which will give you a default value if the bound property is null, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, TargetNullValue=Default}" />
```

If you really want the object type name I would suggest writing a Converter (implement IValueConverter). Let me know if you want a sample converter.

Comment: With your code, I still have empty TextBlocks when my objects havent any Name property. Don't know if it's intended or not. About the Converter, I don't really know, it seems surprising to me that we don't do it simply in the xaml file !

Comment: The property binding will fail in this situation so TargetNullValue will never get used. You can't have a null value for the target if you failed to bind to the target.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood that the property were missing, I just thought it was null ("if Name is empty"). My bad.

Comment: FYI, there is a FallbackValue property on Binding for cases when the binding itself fails, but that only allows fallback to a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

This is theoretical but..

I would create a custom style and target all of your textblocks.  Inside your style, you could set a default text value.  If your binding doesn't override the style, your default value will be used.

```
Style x:Key="TwitterTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
```

Comment: I want the default value to be another Binding, not a static value :(