# Binding to the "object.GetType()"?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an

```
ObservableCollection<object>
```

Let's consider we have 2 items in it :

```
int a = 1;
string str = "hey!";
```

My xaml file acces to it via DataContext and I'd like to display the Type (System.Type) of the object with a Binding.
Here is the code I have

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
```

And I'd like to display in my TextBlocks is :

```
int
string
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Note that, just using the Type.Name you'll get 'Int32' and 'String'.  If you want to use the C# short names, you'll need to write your own function in a ValueConverter (as others have described) to map the Type to a short name.  There is unfortunately no built-in functionality to do this.  You might be able to find some functions others have written, however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use an `IValueConverter` to do this.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public class ObjectToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? null : value.GetType().Name // or FullName, or whatever
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then add it to your resources...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:ObjectToTypeConverter x:Key="typeConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use it on your binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource typeConverter}}" />
```