# Automatically inherit control styles in only one custom window

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am wondering if it is possible to associate Styles for certain controls with a custom window in WPF.

Here's the scenario - I have created a custom window, and have defined styles for a number of controls that I will use in this window.  These are contained in a portable class library.

The catch is that I *only* want the controls to use the style from my library when they are used in the custom window (there are several different windows in the application).

I understand that I can assign the styles a key, and load them from my portable library in my application's app.xaml using pack syntax, for example:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Custom.Application.Library.Controls;component/Styles/CheckBox.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then add and style the control within my custom window as such:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Style="{StaticResource SpecialCheckBox}"
```

But what I would really like to do is define they styles in my class library without a key, as in this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
```

Instead of this:

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
```

So that when this checkbox is used in my custom window it automatically inherits the style.  If I define the style like this, and load it into my app.xaml, the problem is obviously that ALL checkboxes will inherit this style, not just checkboxes used in my custom window.

So, what I'm trying to find out is if there is any way to associate a style resource explicitly with a custom window, so that I can define the styles without a key, and have them by default inherit the "Special" style when used in my custom window, but use the WPF defaults in any other windows of the application.  Does anyone have experience with this?

For clarity here is the code of my custom window:

XAML:

```
<!-- Window style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:CCTApplicationWindow}">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="500"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:CCTApplicationWindow}">
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF999999">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="7"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="29"/>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Controls:CCTApplicationHeader Grid.Row="0" 
                                                           Margin="0" 
                                                           Title="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
                                                           DragMoveCommand="{TemplateBinding DragMoveCommand}" 
                                                           MaximizeCommand="{TemplateBinding MaximizeCommand}" 
                                                           MinimizeCommand="{TemplateBinding MinimizeCommand}" 
                                                           CloseCommand="{TemplateBinding CloseCommand}"/>
                            <Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

CS:

```
public partial class CCTApplicationWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximizeCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaximizeCommand", typeof(DelegateCommand), typeof(CCTApplicationWindow));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimizeCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinimizeCommand", typeof(DelegateCommand), typeof(CCTApplicationWindow));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(DelegateCommand), typeof(CCTApplicationWindow));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DragMoveCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DragMoveCommand", typeof(DelegateCommand), typeof(CCTApplicationWindow));

    public CCTApplicationWindow()
    {
        MaximizeCommand = new DelegateCommand(MaximizeExecute);
        MinimizeCommand = new DelegateCommand(MinimizeExecute);
        CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseExecute);
        DragMoveCommand = new DelegateCommand(DragMoveExecute);
    }

    static CCTApplicationWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CCTApplicationWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CCTApplicationWindow)));
    }

    public DelegateCommand MaximizeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (DelegateCommand)GetValue(MaximizeCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MaximizeCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand MinimizeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (DelegateCommand)GetValue(MinimizeCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MinimizeCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (DelegateCommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand DragMoveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (DelegateCommand)GetValue(DragMoveCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DragMoveCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void MaximizeExecute(object obj)
    {
        if (this.WindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this);
        }
    }

    private void MinimizeExecute(object obj)
    {
        SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
    }

    private void CloseExecute(object obj)
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
    }

    private void DragMoveExecute(object obj)
    {
        DragMove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but you shouldn't! You've tagged this question as MVVM and yet your architecture design breaks MVVM entirely. The whole point of MVVM is that view logic is contained within the view model layer; your view models are the ones that should be keeping track of the logical hierarchy and they are the ones that should be exposing properties to the views to control their appearance. To put it another way, just because XAML is flexible enough and powerful enough to implement such logic doesn't mean it's the best place to actually do it!

To answer your question though, yes, this can be done with a DataTrigger binding to the parent with ObjectToTypeConverter. Here's an example of setting the TextBlock background to CornflowerBlue, unless its immediate parent is a Grid in which case it should be set to PaleGoldenrod:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <converters:ObjectToTypeConverter x:Key="ObjectToTypeConverter" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Parent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type Grid}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Grid Width="100" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="TextBox A" /> <!-- Gets a PaleGoldenrod background -->
    </Grid>
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="TextBox B" /> <!-- Gets a CornflowerBlue background -->
    </Canvas>

</StackPanel>
```

And here's the converter code. It's worth pointing out that if you're happy to simply check that a parent of a given type exists somewhere in the hierarchy (as opposed to the immediate parent) then you don't even need this, you can just attempt to bind to RelativeSource with AncestorType set to the relevant parent type.

```
// based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244658/binding-to-the-object-gettype
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(Type))]
public class ObjectToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? null : value.GetType();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

But again, I implore you, if you really do want to adhere to MVVM then do *not* do it like this! This is exactly the kind of problem that "proper" MVVM was designed to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to create a separate `ResourceDictionary` for your `Custom` window. And use it either using `XAML` or load it using `Code`.